# How can I use doctrine from a static method

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I always use doctrine from controllers or from entity repository classes, now I am trying to use it from a static class but I can't find any example on how to do id.
Basically I'd need (I think) a way to create the entity manager in a static method.

thanks
M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may call a setter function, injecting entity manager, where you call the static method:

**MyController**

```
Class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        SomeClass::setEntityManager($entityManager);
        $result = SomeClass::myStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

**SomeClass**

```
Class SomeClass
{
    private static $entityManager;        

    public static function setEntityManager($entityManager)
    {
        self::$entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function myStaticMethod()
    {
        return $entityManager->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)->findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean you could also just pass the `$entityManager` directly as a parameter then.. would be more straight forward and one less line of code to remember. Additionally `myStaticMethod` would fail if `setEntityManager` wasnt executed in beforehand.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure from your question what you mean by static class/method, some code example might help. But you could declare this class as a service, which it sounds like it might be meant to be anyway, and then inject the entity manager as a dependency.

services.yml

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme\AppBundle\Services\MyService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Then in your class you will have the entity manager available like this:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyService
{

    /**
    * Entity Manager
    *
    * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    ...
}
```

And you can then use this service in your controllers like so:

```
$this->get('my_service')->doSomething();
```

Comment: I know this way to do it but what I need is to make a query from a static method because I need to get the result with a call like 
    $myResult = MyStaticClass::getMyValue($params). So I need to use dotrine from something like public static function getMyValue($params) {}. I'd prefer not to be forced to invoke the constructor. thanks.

Comment: Actually then with the service above, you would just add a method to it called getMyValue($params) and call it like ````$myResult = this->get('my_service')->getMyValue($params)````. No need to invoke the constructor, because the service will have been instantiated and the entity manager injected automatically already at that point.
If your reason for having this static method is "being able to call it conveniently from anywhere" then services are pretty much Symfony's way of doing that, I think.

Comment: thanks I will try it soon! How can I invoke the service from a class that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase?

Comment: From a TestCase you would have to build your own container.  Not an easy thing to do.  Unit tests should not be accessing the database anyways.  If you really feel you need to do this then extend the WebTestCase.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong as the OP clearly states the mandate of access through STATIC method, thus no `__construct`